# Problem with Apache and URLs containin .profile strings

Tags: php, apache, google-oauth

I have come to this peculiar issue where Apache returns a 403 Forbidden message if anywhere in the url the string '.profile' apears.

Specifically I have stumbled upon this issue when trying to use Google's OAuth where after user provides authorization he is redirected back to the original website. In the return url variables are also provided like below

https://example.com/?state=M0L2Bse6HGHDDADgdsfsdfeefsfe3y0G&code=4%2F0AX4XfWiKNFYg4JtLESnSMmhr-HOHcM45mwn48yGSyi8FoTS3hZMZ4aTjjutw_ilUC9ZeNg&scope=email+profile+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&authuser=0&prompt=none#

which include the word '.profile' this will throw a 403 Error.

After a lot of experimenting I have found that removing or altering the '.profile' word in any way allows the request to go through.

I have edited .htacccess and removed all rules just to make sure but still the error persists.

I have also tried deploying the same project on nginx and it runs without any issues. Thus I believe this is Apache specific.

Anyone knows what could be off here?

Comment: You likely got mod_security or some comparable web application firewall running there. https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/issues/1451 describes this exact same issue; apparently blocking this is part of the OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set (CRS) in some form.

Comment: @CBroe, it was indeed the firewall of my server blocking the request due to a custom rule. Thank you for your response, it has helped me troubleshoot the issue.